# android app unfortunately stopped ( database connection )

Tags: java, android, mysql, database, database-connection

I am trying to develop a single `login registeration` page. After following a couple of tutorials i finally found the only tutorial for API 22 because the http post methods used in other tutorials are deprecated.

[**<<<---Tutorial--->>>**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cOsZHuu8Qog)

I haven't followed the whole tutorial because i am stuck at trying to store data into database. My app runs perfectly but when it come to the signup process it says that my app has "unfortunately stopped". I am new to android so please be polite. Below is my `signup.java` and `backgroundtask.java` files.

**i have hosted a free sql database at 000webhost**

```
public class Signup extends Activity{

    Button signupbutt;
    EditText name , username , userpass , dob , email ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.signup);

        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editname);
        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edituser);
        userpass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editpass);
        dob = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editdob);
        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editemail);

        signupbutt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signupbuttonn);
        signupbutt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                userreg(v);
            }
        });
    }

    public void userreg(View view)
    {
        String etname = name.getText().toString();
        String etusername = username.getText().toString();
        String etuserpass = userpass.getText().toString();
        String etemail = email.getText().toString();
        String etdob = dob.getText().toString();
        String method = "Register";
        Backgroundtask backgroundtask = new Backgroundtask(this);
        backgroundtask.execute(method,etname,etusername,etuserpass,etemail,etdob);


    }


}
```

and this is my **backgroundtask.java**

```
public class Backgroundtask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>{
Context ctx;

Backgroundtask(Context ctx)
{
    this.ctx = ctx;

}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPreExecute();
}


@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String reg_url = "http://8miles.freeiz.com/Register.php";

    String method = params[0];

    String name = params[1];
    String username = params[2];
    String password = params[3];
    String email = params[4];
    String dob = params[5];


    try {
        URL url = new URL(reg_url);

        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStream os = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os,"UTF-8"));
        String data = URLEncoder.encode("name","UTF-8") + "="+URLEncoder.encode("name","UTF-8")+"&"+
                 URLEncoder.encode("username","UTF-8") + "="+URLEncoder.encode("username","UTF-8")+"&"+
                URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8") + "="+URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"&"+
                URLEncoder.encode("email","UTF-8") + "="+URLEncoder.encode("email","UTF-8")+"&"+
                URLEncoder.encode("dob","UTF-8") + "="+URLEncoder.encode("dob","UTF-8");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);
}
}
```

Comment: Post your [logCat](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html)?

Comment: You're just creating the outputstream and  then declaring the data - but you're never sending anything. Which line triggers the error? please post a full stacktrace from logcat.

Comment: would post error logcat??

Comment: @alfasin Thankyou you are right i was not sending the data and i was not doing this
   bufferedWriter.write(data);
   bufferedWriter.flush();
   bufferedWriter.close();
   os.close();

Comment: @calvinfly thankyou its working not i was also not requesting internet permission in the androidmanifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou everyone i was not sending the data 
bufferedWriter . write(data)
and also not closing and flushing the buffereddata like this
bufferedWriter . flush
bufferedWriter . close
os.close
Also i was not requesting internet permission in the androidmanifest.xml